# JavaScript: Copy to Clipboard is causing jump to the top of the page (NO ANCHOR TAGS INVOLVED!)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have seen a lot of other questions similar to this, but this one has no anchor tags, and I cannot find an answer without it!

### Problem

Clicking on an element to copy to the clipboard (code provided below) is causing the page to scroll to the top, which is not desired.

### Question

I see it is jumping to the top on the `focus` change, but it's never changing back.  Is there a way to prevent the page jump?

### Code

**JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/myingling/r135zL90/2/**

1
Embedded

```
<style>
div {
  min-height: 500px;
}
.item {
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 3px;
}
</style>
<div>
  <span class='item'>AAA</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span class='item'>BBB</span>
</div>
<div>
   <span class='item'>CCC</span>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(".item").click(function () {
        var success = copyToClipboard(jQuery(this).html());
        if (success) jQuery(this).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    });

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
    // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);
        }
        if(typeof elem == "string") target.textContent = elem;
        else target.textContent = elem.text();
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
        succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    return succeed;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your code calls `copyToClipboard()` with the HTML content of the clicked element, but `copyToClipboard()` appears to expect a DOM element as it's argument. *edit* oh wait, I see; it'll take either an element reference or a string.

Comment: Also to set the value of a `<textarea>` you have to set its "value" property, not the text content.

Comment: As to why it scrolls to the top, you set your "target" element's position to the very top of the viewport (`target.style.top = "0";`).  If you set it to the vertical offset of the clicked element, it'd probably work the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues here:
1- you submit HTML content to your function, while it expects a DOM element.
2- You add that textarea to the top of the page, so the browser scrolls back up to focus.

Solution:
1- Remove `.html()` from `copyToClipboard()` and create a variable at the beginning of that function
2- Add that textarea to the element clicked so the browser does not scroll away from it

Remember to remove the hidden field once used.

Javascript code below

```
    jQuery(".item").click(function () {
        var success = copyToClipboard(jQuery(this));
        if (success) jQuery(this).fadeOut(100).fadeIn(100);
    });

function copyToClipboard(elem) {
    // create hidden text element, if it doesn't already exist
    var copyText = elem.html();
    var targetId = "_hiddenCopyText_";
    var isInput = elem.tagName === "INPUT" || elem.tagName === "TEXTAREA";
    var origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd;
    if (isInput) {
        // can just use the original source element for the selection and copy
        target = elem;
        origSelectionStart = elem.selectionStart;
        origSelectionEnd = elem.selectionEnd;
    } else {
        // must use a temporary form element for the selection and copy
        target = document.getElementById(targetId);
        if (!target) {
            var target = document.createElement("textarea");
            /*target.style.position = "absolute";
            target.style.left = "-9999px";
            target.style.top = "0";
            target.id = targetId;
            document.body.appendChild(target);*/
            target.style.opacity = 0;
            elem.append(target);
        }
        if(typeof elem == "string") target.textContent = elem;
        else target.textContent = elem.text();
    }
    // select the content
    var currentFocus = document.activeElement;
    target.focus();
    target.setSelectionRange(0, target.value.length);

    // copy the selection
    var succeed;
    try {
        succeed = document.execCommand("copy");
    } catch(e) {
        succeed = false;
    }
    // restore original focus
    if (currentFocus && typeof currentFocus.focus === "function") {
        currentFocus.focus();
    }

    if (isInput) {
        // restore prior selection
        elem.setSelectionRange(origSelectionStart, origSelectionEnd);
    } else {
        // clear temporary content
        target.textContent = "";
    }
    target.remove();
    return succeed;
}
```

See if that's what you're looking for: https://jsfiddle.net/yjvstazu

**Side note**: this won't work on iOS. You need to make the input/textarea contentEditable. Add something like this to your code:

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone/i)) {
        target.contentEditable = true;
        target.readOnly = true;
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(target);
        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
        target.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
    } else {
        target.select();
    }
```

Comment: That works, thanks.  I was hoping to keep the copyToClipboard function accepting both a raw string and an element/input value, but you did solve the fiddle.

Comment: If what you're looking to do is be able to copy a text that does not show on the page when a user clicks a button, add data-copy="copy_me" to any element, and instead of calling var copyText = elem.html(), call var copyText = elem.data("copy"). Much more flexible. Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sekvtyuf/

Comment: I actually didn't originate the the copyToClipboard code myself, but I use it in my code for either (1) copying a fixed string, (2) copying the contents of an input or textarea, often a read-only only or (3) using a data tag like you suggest.  That's why the cross-flexibility of it is nice to me.

Comment: If you have a button that triggers the copy-to-clipboard function, add some script to save the text that you want to copy inside the data-copy of your button based on your conditions to determine what to copy. You can create a var text_to_copy and set it the way you want, then add that text to data-copy of your button with setAttribute('data-copy', text_to_copy) or .data('copy', text_to_copy) with Jquery, then call your function copyToClipboard(button)